# How to compile c using cc in Solaris?

Tags: c, solaris, cc

I want to test my program in different OS but `gcc` doesn't really work in Solaris but there's `cc`.

Here's how I compile with gcc :

```
gcc -c quicksort.c sched.c -g -pthread -O3
gcc -o quicksort quicksort.o sched.o -Wall -g -pthread -O3
```

I tried to compile with cc using the same arguments but here's what I get :

```
quicksort.c:
sched.c:
"sched.c", line 233: warning: argument #3 is incompatible with prototype:
        prototype: pointer to function(pointer to void) returning pointer to void : "/usr/include/pthread.h", line 197
        argument : pointer to void

ld: fatal :  soname option (-h, --soname) is incompatible with building a dynamic executable
ld: fatal :  flags processing errors
```

Here's the line that make the first error :

```
pthread_create(&s->tab_thread[i], NULL, (void *) main_thread, new_args_sched(i, s));
```

`new_args_sched` is just a struct for passing args to the function `main_thread`

I don't know what option should I use, I tried with `-mt` and `-lpthread` but it didn't work. I have 3 file `quicksort.c` with the main, `sched.h` and `sched.c`

**Edit**

The Solaris computer is in `ssh` it's not mine and I can't configure it. The version of `gcc` is `3.4.3` using only `C90` my code work with `C11`. Only `cc` should work but I don't know how to compile with it correctly...

I'm using a struct to pass in `main_thread` like this :

```
struct sched_args {
    int i;
    struct scheduler *s;
};

struct sched_args *
new_args_sched(int i, struct scheduler *s) {
    struct sched_args *args = malloc(sizeof(struct sched_args));
    if(args == NULL)
        return NULL;

    args->i = i;
    args->s = s;
    return args;
}
```

and so here's how I get it in my function when I use pthread_create :

```
void main_thread(void *closure) {
    struct sched_args *args = (struct sched_args *)closure;
    int i = args->i;
    struct scheduler *s = args->s
    /* doing something */
}
```

Comment: You can find a `gcc` binary for Solaris, and you can build [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/) from source code on it. You should try `man cc` on your Solaris machine

Comment: You probably should remove the `(void*)` cast to `main_thread` in `pthread_create`. But to be sure, you need to provide some [MCVE]

Comment: Show the signature for `main_thread`.

Comment: Also, what does `new_args_sched(i, s)` return, or is it a macro?

Comment: I edited my post. For the `(void *)` if I don't use it `clang` in my MacOS doesn't recognize it. I'm acceding to the Solaris computer with `ssh` it's from my university and they didn't install the new version of `gcc` in it only `cc`

Comment: *I edited my post. For the (void *) if I don't use it clang in my MacOS doesn't recognize it.* Casting away error and warning messages is the wrong approach.  Now you know why.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This code

```
void main_thread(void *closure) {
    struct sched_args *args = (struct sched_args *)closure;
    int i = args->i;
    struct scheduler *s = args->s
    /* doing something */
}
```

needs to be

```
void *main_thread(void *closure) {
    struct sched_args *args = (struct sched_args *)closure;
    int i = args->i;
    struct scheduler *s = args->s
    /* doing something */
    return( NULL );
}
```

The [`pthread_create()` POSIX-standard function](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/pthread_create.html) has as a prototype

```
int pthread_create(pthread_t *restrict thread,
   const pthread_attr_t *restrict attr,
   void *(*start_routine)(void*), void *restrict arg);
```

Note that the third argument is of type `void *(*start_routine)(void*)` - the address of a function taking a `void *` parameter **and returning a `void *`**.